# Codigo para crear matriz cuadrada "efecto tunel"?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, fórmulas-de-matriz

Estoy teniendo problemas para poder crear una función que genere una matriz cuadrada (sea cual sea es decir si entramos un 8 en la función creara una 8x8) pero que a demás genere un efecto túnel en ella partiendo que la primera capa exterior sea 0, la siguiente interior 1, luego otra vez 0 y así hasta llegar al centro.

Una vez hecho debe representar el gráfico quedando algo así 0 en blanco 1 en negro:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> De momento tengo esto:

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    def mat_gen(x):

        Z = np.zeros((x,x),dtype=int)
        i=0

        while i<=x:
            Z[i:-i,i:-i] = 1
            i=i+1 
        im=plt.imshow(Z) 
        plt.show()
        return 

    mat_gen(12)
```

> estoy encallado con el slicing para pasar a la tercera capa ponerle zeros.. Solo genero un marco de 0 y todo 1 en el interior francamente no se como abordarlo.

> > He conseguido hacer el del tablero de ajedrez, no obstante este... se me escapa.

Muchas gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Puedes por favor añadir lo que has intentado

Comment: Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento: lee [ask].

Comment: @padaleiana disculpar soy nuevo y no sabia como funciona. Espero que ahora este bien formalizada la pregunta y el contenido sea el necesario. Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: @DavidFloresGarcía disculpar soy nuevo y no sabia como funciona. Espero que ahora este bien formalizada la pregunta y el contenido sea el necesario. Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Si creo que la pregunta así tal y como esta ya esta bien formulada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar *modulo* para alternar entre ceros y unos. Y un [colormap](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormaps.html) de blancos y negros:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def mat_gen(x):
    Z = np.zeros((x, x), dtype=int)
    i = 0

    while i <= x:
        Z[i:-i, i:-i] = i % 2
        i = i + 1
    im = plt.imshow(Z, cmap='binary')
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()
    return

mat_gen(50)
```

[image: efecto túnel]

Comment: Muchas gracias !! funciona de lujo!!